# Passing param to java android class

Tags: java, android, constructor

Here is the class i am passing to

```
public class AxxessCCPAccountDetails extends Activity {

public AxxessCCPAccountDetails(String username) {

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accountdetails);
}
```

}

Here is the code that i am passing from

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AxxessCCPAccountList.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
      }
    });
```

I need to pass a username to a class. How can i pass the param to the class then activate the activity(class) which is linked to a view.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");

Answer (score 5):

Using `Intent`. You should not create your own constructor for the `Activity` class.

Here is a short example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AxxessCCPAccountList.class);
myIntent.putExtra("username", userName);
myIntent.putExtra("pass", pass);
```

And then, in your `AxxessCCPAccountList.onCreate` method:

```
String userName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
String pass = this.getIntent.getStringExtra("pass");
```

Comment: String userName = this.getIntent().getExtra("username");

When i try do this it says that getextra does not exist

Comment: I forgot that when gettings extras, you do specify the type. So: `String userName = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("username");`. Ill edit the code now

Answer (score 1):

Add the data to the intent (`intent.putExtra()` or something), and get it on the other side from the intent in `onCreate` (`intent.getExtra()` ) by using the same key.